# JavaScript / jQuery: Load file into variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm pretty new to JS / web development in general, so please forgive me if the question is trivial.

As the title states, I want to load the content of a file into a variable. The first problem I encountered is how to locate the file.

I've found that to load the file into a variable, I could use this code:

```
this.$.get('file.txt', function(response) {
     var myFile = response;
});
```

But the project I work on has a lot of directories, and I do not know which is the.. I don't know, main directory? Directory where the script is executed? I think I've tried to place file.txt into pretty much every possible directory without success.

I've also tried to find the "executive directory" with those commands (again, without success):

```
var script = document.currentScript;
var fullUrl = script.src;
```

This results in script being undefined and terefore script.src causing an error.

I've also tried this:

```
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script"),
    src = scripts[scripts.length-1].src;
```

Resulting in src being an empty string.

Comment: do `'/file.txt'` for loading file.txt always from root-web director

Comment: So what is problem. HOw is the script path correspond to the file path? We need some details to figure out what is going on.

Comment: @johnSmith thanks for the response. I've just tried adding a slash before the filename which sadly didn't help. May you tell me how to find the root web directory?

Comment: @epascarello sadly I can't be more specific because I do not know which informations matter (as I stated, I am very new to this topic). I can place the file where-ever I want, I just have to somehow load it's content into a variable (I simply don't want to hard-code the files content into the code).

Comment: We can not help you if we do not know your specific problem. We do not know were the files are either... The JavaScript runs where the HTML file you are on is at, it has nothing to do with where the JavaScript file was loaded from. Give us a generic file/folder structure where the html page is and where the text file is located.

Comment: @epascarello As I said, I can put the file where-ever I want. I guess there has to be some way to find the path of the currently running script (or the root web directory as johnSmith suggested), so I can use a relative path to the file from there. That's what I tried so far (see the two examples I gave in the question), but couldn't accomplish it. My question is if that's possible or if there's another way to accomplish this?